# iOS enable banner busy spinner?

Tags: ios, multithreading

Is there a way to explicitly enable the banner busy spinner? I have a thread performing some HTTPS requests, and would like to indicate to the user that something is still happening in the background...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you talking about the [Network Activity Indicator](http://oleb.net/blog/2009/09/managing-the-network-activity-indicator/)?